# Security rules for nested subdocuments with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to create a text editor app using firebase that allows users to create documents, but they can also nest a new document inside an existing document (when editing a document, they would be able to click on a button that would add a new document in the database and insert a link in the editor that redirects towards this page):

[image: Nested pages schema]

A user would be able to share a document with other users, but then they should have access to all the nested documents as well. So now I am wondering how to write the security rules to do that.

I think the best way to structure the *realtime database* would be to store all documents at the root, and then add a `parentDocument` or `path` property to each document:

```json
{
  "documents": {
    "doc-1": {
      "title":"Lorem ipsum",
      "content": "...",
      "path":"/",
      "owner":"user-1",
      "canAccess":{
        "user-3":true
      }
    },
    "doc-2": {
      "title":"Dolor sit",
      "content": "...",
      "path":"/doc-1/",
      "owner": "user-1"
      "canAccess": {
        "user-2":true
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "user-1": { ... },
    "user-2": { ... },
    "user-3": { ... }
  }
}
```

↑ In the example below,

- doc-2 is nested inside doc-1
- user-1 can access both doc-1 and doc-2
- user-2 can access doc-2 only
- user-3 can access both doc-1 and doc-2

But now I do not know how to manage the security rules, because to check if a user has access to a specific document, I guess it would need to go through each of its parents (using its `path` or `parentDocument` prop). Perhaps I could also specify the `canAccess` prop on *each* document, but then I would have to update each nested document whenever a parent's `canAccess` prop is updated...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Firebase Realtime Database model [permission automatically cascades](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade) downwards. This means that once you grant a user (read or write) permission on a specific path, they can also access all data under that path. You can never revoke the permission at a lower level anymore.

So your requirement actually matches really nicely with this model, and I'd recommend just trying to implement it and reporting back if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess this would only work if the documents are stored with a nested structure inside the database - which would not be a good practice if a document is like 20 levels deep?

Comment: Oh wait, I misread your data structure. Keeping a flat list is indeed usually better, but here it does mean you'd have to either replicate the `canAccess` to all child nodes, keep an upward pointer for every nested child to the closest complete ACL, or perform a dynamic look up of the parent doc's rules (for each level of nesting you want to allow).